# trans_default_domain Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I change my translation file name (messages.en.yml => ProjectMainBundle.en.yml)

Is there a way to change the default translation domain for all the project and not add trans_default_domain in all my twig pages ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to override

```
vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue
vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogueInterface
```

The default translation domain `messages` is hardcoded in there.

Comment: OK, but I'll neet to override Translation in all of my bundles. I don't know which solution is the proper, using trans_default_domain or override